# How to copy data from one json to another using jq

Tags: json, merge, jq

I have two json inputs and I want [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual) to build a new json copying the elements from the 2nd array to the **corresponding position** in the 1st:

1st json:

```
[
   {"foo": "foo1", "bar": "bar1"},
   {"foo": "foo2", "bar": "bar2"},
   {"foo": "foo3", "bar": "bar3"}
]
```

2nd json:

```
[[
   "baz1",
   "baz2",
   "baz3"
]]
```

expected result:

```
[
   {"foo": "foo1", "bar": "bar1", "baz": "baz1"},
   {"foo": "foo2", "bar": "bar2", "baz": "baz2"},
   {"foo": "foo3", "bar": "bar3", "baz": "baz3"}
]
```

I've tried this command line but it doesn't seems to work

```
jq -n --argfile o1 "1st.json" --argfile o2 "2nd.json" "[$o1 []  | .baz= $o2[][]]"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following adopts a straightforward approach to the point of being a bit pedestrian:

```
jq -s -f merge.jq 1.json 2.json
```

assuming the file `merge.jq` contains:

```
.[1][0] as $two
| .[0]
| reduce range(0; length) as $i (.;
    .[$i].baz = $two[$i] )
```

### Variation

If your jq supports the --argfile option, you can avoid the overhead of "slurping" by running:

```
jq --argfile two 2.json -f merge.jq 1.json
```

assuming `merge.jq` contains:

```
reduce range(0; length) as $i (.; 
  .[$i].baz = $two[0][$i] )
```

Comment: I'm on windows: `jq --argfile two 2.json -f merge.jq 1.json`. Worked as expected! Is it possible to achieve the same result without naming the input `$two`?

Comment: You can choose just about whatever name you like -- but there are some limitations - see https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/How-to:-Avoid-Pitfalls#keywords.