# What is the size of data Github actions can process? Workflow is stuck

Tags: github, curl, github-actions

I wanted to know the size of data GitHub actions can process.
I am using GitHub actions to invoke a REST Api.
The input (POST action: body) to the REST Api is a string which is quite large (String length: 1666652), if the string is stored in a file, the file size is over 1.5 mb.
The issue is GitHub actions workflow is stuck and keeps running.

Note: Same works fine if the string length is smaller.

I have tried a java maven project too wherein the maven project is triggered from GitHub actions to invoke the Api but the results are same.
The same code with same large data wors fine if I invoke from eclipse/Jenkins.

Both tests lead to the conclusion that GitHub is unable to process the large data.
Is the conclusion correct??

**Note: I cannot break up the string and pass it in chunks. The entire string has to be passed as input.**

Thanks in advance.

Update:

Adding part of workflow:

```html
steps:
  - name: converting vqltobase64
    run: |
      echo "get_value=$(base64 -w 0 metadata4.vql | cut -c 5- | iconv -f utf8 -t iso8859-5)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

  - name: flow-target
    run: curl --location 'https://10.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/test/loadFromVQL' --header 'Content-type:application/json' --header 'Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxx' --data '{"name":"test_rev-007","description":"revision_creation","content":"'"${{ env.get_value }}"'"}' > at.json
    
  - name: get target id
    run: |
       echo "get_revision_id= $(jq '.id' at.json)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
       
  - name: print revision id
    run : echo "${{env.get_revision_id }}"
    
  - name: deploy to target env
    run: curl -g --location 'https://10.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/deployments' --header 'Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxx' --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --data '{"revisionIds":[${{env.get_revision_id}}],"environmentId":82,"description":"test"}'`
```

get_value : String with length: 1666652
Tried the option of storing the value (get_value) to a file and reading it from there. Same issues

Comment: GitHub actions has no issues calling a large API payload. What code/action are you using to make this request?

Comment: @jessehouwing: yes I am using curl to invoke the api

Comment: @jessehouwing: strange that the same api works perfectly if the value passed to the api (it’s a post method ) is small. For larger data size, the workflow keeps running indefinitely. It’s not an issue with the api as I have tested the api with the same large data in postman and using rest assured (Java) . Api works perfectly fine with no delay or failure. When it’s invoked from GitHub actions, there are problems

Comment: @jessehouwing: self hosted runner, Ubuntu. No proxy server. Curl ver: 7.88.1. Yes invoking curl directly in the workflow

Comment: No end point protection software . Also just to add : Self hosted runner is hosted on aws.

Comment: If you ssh into the aws machine, same issue? If you use one of the dnbug-with-ssh actions from the marketplace, can you replicate the behavior? There is nothing in the runner tha should cause this behavior.

Comment: No there is no issues when I ssh into the machine. I cannot replicate it any way. Whenever GitHub actions comes into the picture there is an issue. According to GitHub docs the variable size limit is 48 kb for a workflow run. But does it mean that if I run a Java maven project from actions workflow it uses the variable in some way. Using curl in GitHub actions gives the issue, running a Java maven project from GitHub actions gives the same issue. There is no other way to replicate it

Comment: You really should share part of your workflow. Are you saying you're passing a 1.5MB variable into the call to curl in a run action? Or passing the return value indo a variable?

Comment: Added the part of the workflow.
I have done the same thing in Java and running the java project from Github actions : Same issue

Comment: A 1.5MB long commandline might indeed cause issues. Try passing the variable through the bash environment instead of inlining it in the call: `run: curl $VALUE` with `env: VALUE: ${{ env.get_value }}`. But probably much better would be to create a file with the full payload and then `cat file | curl` without relying on the GitHub env at all. There isn't really any good reason why all of these steps are seperate run steps and passing values through the runner. By just making it 1 multiline script you can manipulate everything in bash.

Comment: I tried both the approaches but the issue persists. Even I read it from a file directly the workflow keeps running without an error or a failure. Regarding adding everything to one line can be done yes but if the basic workflow isn’t working then optimising the code is not the priority

Comment: It's not optimizing the code, it's doing away geth saving the data in the GitHub env completely.

Answer (score 0):

This is guessing, since I am unable to test your code, but I would highly advise against passing this large an amount of data over an environment variable, let alone across step boundaries.

Instead of a relying on environment storage I'd recommend storing directly in a file instead:

```
echo '{"name":"test_rev-007","description":"revision_creation","content":"' > payload.json
echo "$(base64 -w 0 metadata4.vql | cut -c 5- | iconv -f utf8 -t iso8859-5)" >> payload.json
echo '"}' >> payload.json
```

Instead of string concatenation, [you could also rely on jq to inject your data into a json template. That way you are 100% certain of any weird escapes and qoutes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52446722/736079).

You can then pass the file directly to curl:

```
curl --data -@ < payload.json
```

You may potentially need:

```
curl --binary-data -@ < payload.json
```

And when you do want to pass a variable in (in the case of the revisionid), make sure to pass if from the environment section instead of inlining it:

```
- run: curl -g --location 'https://10.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/deployments' --header 'Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxx' --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --data '{"revisionIds":[$revisionId],"environmentId":82,"description":"test"}'`
  env:
     revisionId: ${{env.get_revision_id}}
```

And by removing the individual steps and just using a single `run:` block you don't need any gethub environment variables at all and can simply rely on the built-in bash constructs. This makes it much easier to test your scripts locally too:

```
- run: |
    value=$(base64 -w 0 metadata4.vql | cut -c 5- | iconv -f utf8 -t     
 
    curl --location 'https://10.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/test/loadFromVQL' --header 'Content-type:application/json' --header 'Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxx' --data '{"name":"test_rev-007","description":"revision_creation","content":"'"$value"'"}' > at.json

    revision_id=$(jq '.id' at.json)"

    echo "$revision_id"

    curl -g --location 'https://10.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/deployments' --header 'Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxx' --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --data '{"revisionIds":[$revision_id],"environmentId":82,"description":"test"}'`
```

As you can see, no need for variables and other github agent specific things. And this script can easily be placed in a separate `.sh` file so you can run it locally too.